# Intermittent unit test failures in sqlAlchemy due to database not being dropped

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a collection of unit tests that run in a gitlab pipeline.  The following code is meant to rebuild the database between tests.  It works most of the time, but does not work every time, causing the pipeline to fail on some random test.

```
    @pytest.fixture
    def apply_migrations():
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            drop_database_connections(conn, cfg.POSTGRES_DB)
            conn.execute(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "{cfg.POSTGRES_DB}"')
            conn.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE "{cfg.POSTGRES_DB}" TEMPLATE {template_db_name}')
```

This code will create an error message like the following:

```
self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x7f1762ec6f70>
cursor = <cursor object at 0x7f175f654a90; closed: -1>
statement = 'CREATE DATABASE "test" TEMPLATE template_db_23381'
parameters = {}
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGExecutionContext_psycopg2 object at 0x7f175f343eb0>
    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_database_datname_index"
E       DETAIL:  Key (datname)=(test) already exists.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:732: UniqueViolation
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    @pytest.fixture
    def apply_migrations():
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            drop_database_connections(conn, cfg.POSTGRES_DB)
            conn.execute(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "{cfg.POSTGRES_DB}"')
>           conn.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE "{cfg.POSTGRES_DB}" TEMPLATE {template_db_name}')
/app/services/api/tests/conftest.py:116:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1274: in execute
    return self._exec_driver_sql(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1578: in _exec_driver_sql
    ret = self._execute_context(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1845: in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2026: in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:207: in raise_
    raise exception
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1802: in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x7f1762ec6f70>
cursor = <cursor object at 0x7f175f654a90; closed: -1>
statement = 'CREATE DATABASE "test" TEMPLATE template_db_23381'
parameters = {}
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGExecutionContext_psycopg2 object at 0x7f175f343eb0>
    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_database_datname_index"
E       DETAIL:  Key (datname)=(test) already exists.
E       
E       [SQL: CREATE DATABASE "test" TEMPLATE template_db_23381]
E       (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:732: IntegrityError
```

Why does this database still exist sometimes after being dropped?  Using postgres 12.7 and sqlalchemy 1.4.31.

I've tried to research this and found very little information.

Comment: Semantics: This is not a unit test, but an integration test.

Comment: Are there any other tests being executed concurrently on the cluster? If you disable those other tests, do you still get the error?

Comment: @THX1138 There are cypress tests that run in parallel.  I'm talking to the ops team about changing those to run in series.  Thanks for the idea; I'll report back later.

Comment: It took a very long time to get ops to switch things over, but now that they have we no longer see this error.  So you were most likely right. Thanks.